# Flutter Install on Linux creating issues -Flutter Doctor

Tags: linux, android-studio, flutter, ubuntu, dart

I have flutter and Android Studio installed via snap on my Ubuntu, dart and flutter plugins are also installed in android studio. Also that I tried changing directories for the android studio but did'nt work. SDK paths for both the flutter and dart are already added. Kindly help me with this. [Flutter Doctor Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZhnQ.jpg)

Comment: You can find similar issues in Flutter GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71210) and on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63356096/flutter-not-detecting-android-studio).

Comment: Tried everything, but unable to figure out the exact issue. Reset my whole setup and configured everything from the start. Now it's working.