# flutter doctor can't find android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I'm starting with flutter.
after installing flutter and dart plugins in android studio and downloading flutter SDK
flutter doctor couldn't recognize android studio. I used
`flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"`
in cmd.
now flutter doctor recognize android but error is this

```
[!] Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
```

Comment: Try to uninstall flutter and dart plugin and restart the android studio and reinstall flutter and dart again. Sometimes it will work.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it before but it is the same again

Comment: check this one may help you :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59647791/tag-android-studio-not-installed-when-run-flutter-doctor-while-android

Answer (score 6):

I once tried with ***flutter config --android-studio-dir C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio*** but unfortunately it does not work because of empty space which breaks the tree structure. Later I used the quotes like this: ***flutter config --android-studio-dir "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"***. I hope it works!

Answer (score 2):

Flutter can recognize Android Studio. But you have to **restart** Android Studio after installation.
You can follow [these instructions](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor):

```
To install these:

Start Android Studio.
Open plugin preferences (Configure > Plugins as of v3.6.3.0 or later).
Select the Flutter plugin and click Install.
Click Yes when prompted to install the Dart plugin.
Click Restart when prompted.
```

Comment: Thank you. But I did restart android studio

Answer (score 2):

To avoid breaking the path structure, change the command to
flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"
include "=" between ..."dir=C:\

Comment: The equals isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

flutter config --android-studio-dir "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio".

this answer works for me

Answer (score 1):

My advice for you is to uninstall this android studio version you have completely, then downgrade the version and then try again, I had this issue and I did that. I am using Android Studios 4.0.2 now.

Answer (score 1):

@Hammad Ali Shah was almost there.

Just use `flutter config --android-studio-dir "C:\\Program Files\\Android\\Android Studio"`.

Answer (score 0):

No sure if this helps anyone else. For me the issue was that I has installed Android Studio P (preview) as well as Android Studio and even though I point flutter to use Android Studio it was somehow using Android Studio P!

What I did is simply removed Android Studio P and then all was fine!. Hopefully this helps someone out there.