# Flutter Doctor doesn't recognize Android Studio and flutter dart plugins plugins New version 4.1 Update

Tags: android-studio, flutter

[image: Flutter Doctor -v gives followings]

[image: Here Also I have Android studio Lates version]

How can I fix this issue
And also I have JDK 8

[Installed flutter dart plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOek5.png)

[image: Flutter doctor result]

Comment: Where is your Android Studio?

Comment: 1st-row third column app it is the new version of android studio

Comment: is this helped ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59647791/tag-android-studio-not-installed-when-run-flutter-doctor-while-android

Comment: yes but plugins are not recognized

Comment: Hey @DinethSGimhana have you tried restarting your terminal after installing the plugins on Android Studio (Which at the same time needs android studio to be restarted to validate the plugins installation)?

Comment: yes I have done

Comment: I finally decided to downgrade until this is fixed. I didn't realize how much I depended on these plugins until they were gone. Downgrading is not the nightmare I thought it would be either. Uninstall the one you have, install the older version. No hiccups.

Comment: I did some followup reading, and [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61246) is worth paying attention to. IMO, the right solution isn't to simply disable the validity check; Some proactive warning needs to take its place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug with Android Studio Version 4.1.

Your choices are either to downgrade to 4.0, or wait for an update. The issue is with Android Studio, not the plugins.There is no known workaround to make the plugins work until the Android Studio team fixes it.

See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67986 for details.

Comment: FYI I ended up downgrading because the Flutter plugins are so valuable to me. I've seen recent notices of upgrades, but I haven't pulled the trigger because I don't know if this issue has been fixed.