# I have problem with gradle in flutter. Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

**Here is the error:**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'E:\proj\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\patel.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

---

I already change JDK 16 to 8 and update Gradle version.

Answer (score 13):

I added this line to **./android/gradle.properties** for **OSX** `org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home`
Android Studio changed their file path for the jre so I think this will go away once flutter fixes with a new version

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks. The originally answer gets the upvote :)

Comment: not worked for me. I got this error ```Value '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid (Java home supplied is invalid)```

Comment: Works! Upvoted :-)
But what is behind this problem? Why did it happen?

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks

Comment: Change to 'org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home' worked. Just change **jre** in the original answer to **jbr**. Upvoted and thanks! Android Studio version: Electric Eel | 2022.1.1

Comment: What is ./android/gradle ? Where do I find it?  I have .android and .gradle in my user folder but what they don't have gradle.properites.

Comment: Really work for me thank-you you save my time buddy 
just adding this line 
$org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home

and react native app working fine 
Thank-you

Answer (score 6):

In gradle.properties, try to add that `org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Android\\Android Studio\\jre`

Comment: You can also check that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59647791/tag-android-studio-not-installed-when-run-flutter-doctor-while-android

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this issue you have to follow these steps, they worked for me:

1. Go to your **gradle-wrapper.properties** file and change the gradle plug-in version to the latest.
   e.g
   **distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip**

It means 7.2 is the latest as at the time of writing this.

NOTE: Open your flutter app:
**android>gradle>wrapper>gradle-wrapper.properties**

2. Then, open your app and go to:
   **android>build.gradle**

open the file and in the buildScript and under the dependencies block,
give a compactible version to the Gradle.

An example is shown below.

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
  repositories {
      google()
      mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
  }
}
```

3. In your manifest file:
   **android>app>src>main>androidManifest.xml**

open it and under the activity tag, add: **android:exported="true"**

You can then invalidate caches and rebuild your project.
try it and give me feedback.

Reference is from the official doc

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Comment: Please use proper markup for code sections.

Answer (score 2):

I added this line to `./android/gradle.properties` for `OSX`:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home
```

This is what worked for me.

Comment: you literally copied my answer instead of giving me an upvote with a comment of "this is what worked for me". (look at the timestamps)

Answer (score 2):

This happens, because gradle and Java versions are incompatible. For my case, it was about JDK in gradle settings. All of the answers above didn't help me. I've solved by myself.

What I did:

1. I opened the project structure (File -> Project Structure) in Android Studio, navigated to the "SDK Location" tab and then clicked to "Gradle Settings":

[image]

2. In gradle settings, I changed the gradle JDK's version to the compatible one:

[image]

for example, in the image above, I'm using gradle 6.7.1 and JDK 15.0.2 - which are compatible.

Make sure your gradle and Java versions are compatible. You can check the compatibility table here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

Answer (score 0):

How I resolve the issue on my macOS
1, run; flutter doctor
2, run; sudo gem install cocoapods.
After the lengthy installation, I run again, flutter doctor. and it was SOLVED.

For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins

To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/gettingstarted.html#installation for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

In gradle wrapper.properties, change the code to this -

```
distribution Url = https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

In build.gradle, change the code to this -

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3"
```